# Incorrect result for Integrate[] over Region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

I was doing a calculation that involved integrating rational functions over a triangular region, and eventually noticed some of my results didn't make any sense. After some investigating, I was able to track it down to

```
Integrate[1/x, {x, y} \[Element] Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]

> -1
```

which is a strange answer. It emits no warnings about nonconvergence, either. Is there some way to work around this issue and help Mathematica alert me when I'm asking to Integrate[] over a region, but the integral doesn't converge?

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 evaluates `\[Infinity]`

Comment: Please don't use the `bugs` tag: The tag wiki says: "This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions." That said, if this really *does* spit out `-1`, then that is likely a bug.

Comment: That said, when I evaluate that integral in version "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)", it outputs `Infinity`.

Comment: ```intg = With[{ϵ = t},
   Integrate[
    1/x, {x, y} ∈ 
     Triangle[{{ϵ, ϵ}, {ϵ, 
        1}, {1, ϵ}}]]
   ];
intg = FullSimplify[intg, t >= 0]```
 Then you can do `Limit[intg, t -> 0]`. 
Your code outputs -1 on MMA 14.0 on windows, so looks like a bug.

Comment: I also get `-1` in 13.3/Windows

Comment: With 14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit), I get `-1`

Comment: Other representations produce unevaluated integrals, e.g: `intg = With[{ϵ = 0}, Integrate[Boole[y < 1 - x]/x, {x, ϵ, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]` and using limits also `intg = With[{ϵ = 0}, Integrate[1/x, {x, ϵ, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]]`  so I'd wager the problem is how Mathematica converts regions to integrals internally.

Comment: I reported this as a bug.

Comment: Also `NIntegrate[1/x, {x, y} \[Element] Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}],  Exclusions -> (x == 0)]` produces `0.` and "NIntegrate::moptxn: The option SymbolicProcessing of the method FiniteElement is not one of {Method,MeshOptions}" in 14.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: `f[ϵ_] := 
  Integrate[
   1/x, {x, y} ∈ 
    Polygon[{{ϵ, 0}, {1, 0}, {ϵ, 1}}], 
   Assumptions -> ϵ > 0];
Limit[f[ϵ], ϵ -> 0]
(*  ∞ *)`  I think maybe Mathematica use `Legesgue Integral ` instead of  `Riemannian Integral`

Answer (score 0):

The answer $-1$ is strange indeed. I would expect Mathematica to blindly apply consecutive integration to get
''
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac 1x dy \,dx = \int_0^1[y/x]_{y=0}^{y=x}dx = \int_0^1 1 dx = 1
$$
''
which is still a wrong result... In fact, the existence of the iterated integrals does not guarantee the existence of the double integral. The other order of integration gives you
''$$
\int_0^1\int_0^y \frac 1x dx\,dy=\int_0^1[\log x]_{x=0}^{x=y} \,dy
$$''

Depending on your application, a possible remedy could be to use `NIntegrate[]` instead of `Integrate[]`. It still gives a bogus final result, but alerts you for possible non-convergence.

Comment: Although probably a correct assessment, this does not appear to answer the question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey It does give a partial answer... Using NIntegrate[] instead of Integrate[] produces a warning regarding convergence problems. If this is a viable fix or not is up to the OP, as he did not disclose the exact appication.